# How to retrieve SQL error message and display it with ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to show my SQL Server error to the user. When a method returns a value there is no problem with this code.

But when there is no record I want to give an error message which gets retrieved from a reader.

Here is what I tried:

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
        //It works ok when there is a retrieved date
        var expenses = context.GetAll(GetUserId());
        
        //I think it`s like this. But it says there is a problem with view.
        foreach (var item in expenses)
        {
            if (item.Error != null)
            {
                ViewBag.Error = item.Error;
                return View();
            }
        }
        return View(expenses);
    }
```

I get this error:

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
> Parameter name: source .

In my index view where I say:

```
@if (Model.Any())
{
   html...
}
else
{
  Viewbag.Error
}
```

C# method:

```
public IQueryable<Expenses> GetAll(string UserId)
{
        List<Expenses> expenses = new List<Expenses>();

        using (DALC.GetConnection())
        {
            DALC.Command("spGetUserExpenses");

            DALC.cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = UserId;
            using (SqlDataReader reader = DALC.cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Expenses entities = new Expenses
                        {
                            Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Id"]),
                            TotalAmount = Convert.ToDouble(reader["Amount"]),
                            Desription = reader["Notes"].ToString(),
                            Date = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Date"]),
                            IsCash = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["IsCash"]),
                            IsCard = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["IsCard"])
                        };
                        expenses.Add(entities);
                    }
                }

                if (reader.NextResult())
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    //setting second select statement which is an error by my side?
                    expenses.Add(new Expenses { Error = reader[0].ToString() });
                }
            }
        }

        return expenses.AsQueryable();
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetUserExpenses]
    @UserId nvarchar(450)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        e.ID,
        e.Amount,
        e.Notes,
        e.[Date],
        e.IsCash,
        e.IsCard
    FROM
        Expenses e
    WHERE 
        UserId = @UserId
        AND DATENAME(YEAR, CAST(e.[Date] AS varchar)) = DATENAME(YEAR, GETDATE()) 
        AND DATENAME(MONTH, CAST(e.[Date] AS varchar)) = DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) 
    ORDER BY 
        e.ID DESC

    IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT N'No Expense Found'
    END
END
```

Comment: Where does the error happen? Does the vewi expect a valid ID? Aside from your question: `if (reader.HasRows)` is unnecessary. Also `DATENAME(YEAR,...` is very inefficient especially against an index, better to do `e.[Date] >= DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1) AND e.[Date] < DATEADD(day, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE()))` note the use of half-open interval.

Comment: @Charlieface hello. The problem was with the stored procedure. I deleted the parts you told me and it worked. But I did not get your suggestion. I want to show to a user the expenses of the current month.

Comment: Is your error fixed now? My suggestion was simply to use a date interval, rather than using functions on the date column, because functions mean it won't use the index.

Comment: @Charlieface yeah, it works now. but I did not know what was got to do with that sp.

Comment: @Charlieface https://i.paste.pics/BAIBA.png  have look what your suggestion says

Comment: Sorry you can add `,0` for the extra parameters, or use `DATEFROMPARTS`, depending whether your column is `datetime` or `date` respectively

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this way to select data from stored procedures, it works for me

```
connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("spGetUserExpenses", connection);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    
                //CARA 1
                if (userid == null)
                {
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", DBNull.Value)
                }
                else
                {
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", UserId)
                }
    
    IDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
    
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Expenses entities = new Expenses()
                    {
                        Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Id"]),
                                TotalAmount = Convert.ToDouble(reader["Amount"]),
                                Desription = reader["Notes"].ToString(),
                                Date = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Date"]),
                                IsCash = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["IsCash"]),
                                IsCard = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["IsCard"])
                    };
    
                    expenses.Add(entities);
                }
    
                reader.Close();
                connection.Close();
    
                return expenses;
```

Comment: Where are your `using` blocks?

Comment: i said there is no problem with the code when there is a data retrieved..